# Is there any formal statistical theory of social science research in which researchers often have to reinterpret the same data?

Tags: experiment-design, social-science

When the scientist can control variables and design experiments, standard statistics (hypothesis testing, etc) applies. If needed, the scientist can always redo an experiment to get more data.

In much of social sciences, however, researchers often "revisit" the same data/historical incident with different interpretations, so they routinely *reuse* past "experiments", even though they cannot generate new data. This is somewhat problematic, as standard hypothesis tests no longer applies, but social scientists often have no better alternative.

Is there any formal theory that helps us better understand observational learning?

Comment: There is plenty of work on how to draw valid inferences from observational data. This is frequently discussed in the context of *causal inference*, so you could start by taking a look at the questions tagged causality (DAGs and Judea Pearl come up quite a lot, but there's more to it than that): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causality?tab=Votes

Comment: @mkt I agree. My question is more about how to deal with the fact that social scientists often have to revisit the same data/historical periods and generate new insights, even though they can't generate new data. I've revised my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ah, so your question is about data re-use. 

"*...standard hypothesis tests no longer applies, but social scientists often have no better alternative*" 

This doesn't fully address your question, but Bayesian methods are always an alternative and ameliorate the problem at least somewhat.

Comment: @mkt Can you elaborate a bit more on which Bayesian methods can address this issue? (On another note, I thought you were going to talk about multiple hypothesis testing adjustments...)

Comment: I don't have the time to formulate an answer, but avoiding the yes/no formulation of hypothesis testing is almost always an improvement (not just in your situation). I'm sceptical about the utility of multiple testing adjustments, it's just shifting the yes/no threshold. And even in principle, I can't see any reasonable or coherent way to do such an adjustment for some datasets, for e.g. country GDP estimates.

Comment: There are probably tens to hundreds of thousands of studies that have already used the data, and <200 countries, so achieving a threshold of significance might be near impossible for any new study. Do new studies deserve to be penalised more than those that got lucky and published a few years ago, when the data is basically the same? It's just a morass that is best avoided by abandoning the NHST philosophy, at least in these cases.

Comment: @mkt I agree with your point about multiple hypothesis testing. I think the Bayesian perspective simply means "bring in reasonable priors". A new study will not be just judged on the data (likelihood), but also on the posterior? Is that roughly what you have in mind?